# Alter where a form redirects_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is how user confirmation works when a user (who isn't signed in) follows the confirmation link I sent them in an email:

*update:* Okay, thinking about it, user confirmation is simply to test that an email address exists, and is nothing to do with security. Saying that, I'd still like to know how to change where form's redirects to, using this question as an example.

> ```
> they follow confirm path -> redirect to sign in form -> they sign in correctly -> 
> they have to follow link again -> they reach the confirm action -> they are confirmed
> ```

This is a bit clumsy. I would rather this happens:

> ```
> they follow confirm path -> redirect to sign in form -> they sign in correctly -> 
> they reach the confirm action -> they are confirmed
> ```

I want to eliminate the need for following the link a second time, but I am unsure of how to proceed with this. Here is my sign_in form:

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label 'Email address' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter email' %><br>

    <%= f.label 'Password' %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter password' %><br>


    <%= f.submit 'Sign In', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
```

Which passes its parameters onto my sessions#create action:

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase )

    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        sign_in(user)
        redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Wrong email or password!'
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Now I believe the key is on line 5 of the action:

```
redirect_to user_path(current_user)
```

That needs to be changed. I'm sure I could hack something together here but I want to know how you would tackle the problem.

- The confirm_path's action has to set a variable that will store the new path we want.
- The create actions redirect_to should then use this variable over its default user_path
- The variable should then be emptied so signing in again doesn't redirect to the confirm action.
- Where should this variable be stored in order to do this? In the session?
- How should I solve this problem in the most open ended way, so that I can easily do this for other forms if needs be?
- Bearing this in mind, the variable where we store the paths should maybe be a hash, will several key value pairs. Then, the create actions of our dynamic forms only check the key value that's relevant to them.
- I am allergic to gems as they stop people learning, however if you know of any that do this I would still like to know. But show me how to do it for myself first please :)

Comment: Normally you just mail a long cryptographically secure random key in  a link to a confirm action in some controller, and this this action uses the key to find the user it refers to, then flips a status field in `User` that shows she is confirmed and renders the normal login.  When she logs in, all the site's functionality is presented.  Before then the login fails with a message that confirmation is still required.  This is simpler to implement than what you're trying, and simpler to use, too.

Comment: @Gene From a ux point of view that could be one way to do it, but what happens if someone submits the random key of another user (through reading their emails)? It's an edge case, but it would still mean its possible for a user to be registered when they are not.

Comment: Confirmation has nothing to do with registration except to ensure that the user's stated email address is a real one before the account is enabled with whatever functions the system provides.  That goal is accomplished even if - for some crazy reason - a registered but unconfirmed user forwards the confirmation email to someone else, who does hits the link on their behalf.  The security on the account is the password.

Comment: @Gene Haha, yeah I was thinking that. Okay, fair enough. I'd still like to know how to programatically change where forms take people though.

Comment: I outlined how this could work below.

Comment: Actually, major forums do actually require you to log in before you confirm. Just saying

Comment: Small remark: why not use the devise gem, where all this is built in automatically, and takes care of all known security issues as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Saying that, I'd still like to know how to change where form's redirects to, using this question as an example.

I can give you an idea and the most general practice followed by everyone.

You just have to save the requested path if the user is not signed in and redirect to that part. Devise gem also uses the same strategy, if you're using that you can take its advantage.

I am describing the general solution. To save and get the stored location, you need two methods in `application` controller

#### `store_location` : for storing the location so we will redirect it after signin.

```
def store_location(location)
  if location
    uri = URI.parse(location)
    session["return_path"] = [uri.path.sub(/\A\/+/, '/'), uri.query].compact.join('?')
  end
end
```

#### `stored_location`: for retrieving the saved location (attempted location). Also delete the session path(i will explain it in last part).

```
def stored_location
 location = session["return_path"]
 session.delete("return_path")
 location
end
```

you have to do something like this in your `confirmation` controller

```
before_action: authenticated!

def authenticated!
  unless signed_in?
    store_location_for(request.original_url)
    redirect_to sign_in_path
  end
end
```

you have to just customise `session#create` controller, something like this will work.

```
 redirect_to stored_location ||  user_path(current_user)
```

Now, consider your senerio

1. they follow confirm path
2. redirect to sign in form (it also stores the confirm path location in session)
3. they sign correctly and **they will be redirected to confirm path, so we eliminated the extra step**
4. Let suppose used confirmed, does something and signout. He visited site, clicked signin button and tries to do signin normally. **if we didn't removed/deleted his last attempted url from session, he will be redirected to same place, to avoid this we did `session.delete("return_path")`**.

I hope this makes it clear.

PS: the above code is the abstract idea, if you have role based app, you have to scope location differently, I haven't explained that thing since it is far beyond this topic. If you want to learn more you can read [`devise` gem specs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/13a8ad81ee2b27d2aae60dfc70fa0c80992350bc/test/controllers/helpers_test.rb)

Comment: Good answer. Imho OP should just use devise directly though :)

Answer (score 2):

In line with our comments, I'd first create a confirmation model.

```
rails g model Confirmation key:string user_id:integer
```

You can generate the random hash with a callback:

```
require 'securerandom'
  ...
  before_validation :generate_random_key
  belongs_to :user  
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id
  ...
  private

  def generate_random_key
    self.key = SecureRandom.hex(32)
  end
```

Then the controller for creating a new registration adds a record to this model for the new user.  Additionally, it will be appropriate for the `User` model to have a `has_one :confirmation` relationship. (Rails `has_one` actually means zero or one.)

Next make a confirmation controller to set the status of the user to "confirmed". Something like:

```
rails g controller confirmation new
```

Then I'd edit `config/routes.rb` to use a singular CRUD resource path, since there is only

```
resource :confirmation, only: :new
```

With this, the path placed in your email message should look something like:

```
.../confirmation?key=<long hex string>
```

and the controller:

```
class ConfirmationController < ApplicationController

  def new
    key = params[:key]
    user = key && User.joins(:confirmation).where(key: key)
    if user
      user.confirmation.destroy  # Kill the confirmation. It's not needed any more.
      user.confirmed = true      # Mark the user confirmed
      user.save!                 # Update her record.
      flash[:alert] = 'Your registration has been confirmed. Log in for full service!'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Your confirmation link is broken or expired. Log in to request a new one.'
    end
    redirect_to controller: :sessions, :action: :new 
  end

end
```

The session controller should redirect to a "no services" landing page that's shown upon login of an unconfirmed user.  Just about the only thing there will be a link to request a new confirmation email.  For a confirmed user login, it redirects instead to the full service landing page.

Delete any old confirmation record that exists for a user before creating a new one.  Use a background job to expire unused ones if desired.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a variation on Paritosh's solution that passes the redirect URL around as a parameter rather than storing it in the session. It's more vulnerable to XSS attacks (so you need to be careful with validation in your redirect), but it doesn't break if a user opens multiple tabs to different pages on your site before signing in. That's a pet peeve of mine :).

The basic idea is your authentication check always passes on the destination path when redirecting to the sign in form:

```
# Variation on Paritosh's solution
before_action: authenticated!

def authenticated!
  unless signed_in?
    uri = URI.parse(request.original_url)
    redirect_to sign_in_path(redirect_path: [uri.path.sub(/\A\/+/, '/'), uri.query].compact.join('?'))
  end
end
```

then your sign in form passes that path along with the username and password

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag(:redirect_path, params[:redirect_path]) if params[:redirect_path] %>
    <%= f.label 'Email address' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter email' %><br>

    <%= f.label 'Password' %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter password' %><br>


    <%= f.submit 'Sign In', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
```

then the Sessions controller redirects to that path (if it's valid)

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase )

    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        sign_in(user)
        redirect_path redirect_path || user_path(current_user)
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Wrong email or password!'
        render 'new'
    end
end

private

def redirect_path
    params[:redirect_path] if params[:redirect_path] && params[:redirect_path] =~ /\A\/[^\/]/
end
```

If you're using a subdomain for your sign in service, you can pass a full URL instead of just a path. In that case you'll need to verify that the hostname in the URL is one that you own.